# Ruby -- Escape Single quote in variable name

Tags: css, ruby, string

I have this:  `my_variable = "You\'re It"`

I want to find it on the page in an a tag so if I do:

```
page.parser.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'#{my_variable}')]")
page.parser.css('a:contains("#{temp_account_name}")')
page.parser.css("a:contains('#{temp_account_name}')")
```

I get an error for all the above.

But if I do:

```
page.parser.css('a:contains("You\'re It")')
```

it works. The problem is I can't use this above and place a variable in there.

How do I escape a `'` character when using a variable and parsing it from the page?

On the page the text I am searching for is You're It. So I added the escape character to my variable to match and find what is on the page.

Comment: You could try escaping the \ in the variable: `my_variable = "You\\'re It"`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Nokogiri or xpath, it's a string quoting and interpolation problem.

Comment: @MrLister That isn't working when I do that I get this error SyntaxError: Invalid expression: //a[contains(text(),'You\'re It')]

Answer (score 0):

Try unescaping all the characters:

```
my_variable.gsub /[^\\](\\)[^\\]/, ''
```

Comment: I edited my post.  The issue is on the page the text contains the ' so I need it in my_variable to search for the exact string on the page.

Answer (score 0):

...I think this is asp.net? If so, use .replace("'", "''") .  Interesting solutions also exist with Server.HTMLEncode, but that's more for URLS.